# Delphi XE2 prompted me that file date/time has changed, but it didn't. Should I be worried?

Tags: delphi, datetime, ide, delphi-xe2

I have left my Delphi IDE open on my work computer overnight with a project open. Just now, I connected to my work computer via Windows Remote Desktop, and was prompted...

```
Module [file path.pas]'s time/date changed. Reload?
```

The same message appeared for each and every file in the project which was open.

Should I be worried about this? Did anything really change? I checked the source and nothing is different.

Comment: I don't agree with person who gave `-1`, so `+1`

Comment: Reported it 5 years ago: [QC#68312](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=68312). It was worse then, the IDE wouldn't survive DST change.

Comment: @Sertac, well, but how to fix that. The `WM_TIMECHANGE` message is broadcasted after the system restore (as far as I remember), but I'd say you first detect the file change than receive `WM_TIMECHANGE`.

Comment: @TLama - Maybe. Actually I never thought about it. The reported bug was about IDE not being able to handle the change about the project group file. You had to kill the IDE to be able to get rid of the question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz In your QC report, you say you have to manually kill the IDE, that it doesn't shut down respectively. I didn't face that issue.

Comment: @Jerry - I noticed. That's why I said *"It was worse then .."*. D2009 was the latest version at the time.

Comment: Boy I wish they'd fix this one.

Comment: 3 years later and I let this happen again...

Comment: Delphi 10 Seattle, still doing this.

Comment: And yet again, 2018, and I STILL forgot to close my IDE. Delphi 10.1 Berlin, still not fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just so happens that Daylight Savings Time has just ended, where all areas which observe it have just gone back an hour in time. The Delphi IDE does not know this, and therefore the date/time of all the files open will be an hour different from reality.

I expect that a lot of people will be seeing this today or tomorrow, or whenever they get back to their IDE which was left open during the time change.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't believe that there is such a bug in IDE.

Comment: I can believe it. Can't be too perfect.

Comment: It never was and never be perfect, but ffs... this is serious bug that should be fixed versions ago.

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue in the IDE. Interesting note is that it only shows the message for files which are currently open in the editor, but not for files which are part of the project but not currently open in an editor tab/window.

Comment: Also, if you find this annoying... I could write a simple self-installing plugin to fix it :)

Comment: Well I happened to have every file in the project open, even the project's main file

Comment: It was early this morning, at least here in Louisville, KY, USA

Comment: But I don't consider it any serious IDE bug at all, but just an inconvenience where if you don't realize why it happened, it can be very confusing and makes you worry.

Comment: Ah, "here in USA". We don't all have the same DST!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess not, never knew that.

Comment: @Flash: Why is this an "IDE bug"? The IDE had open files, and the system time changed. Now the dates/times of the open files doesn't match what's on disk. The IDE asked if they should be reloaded, because it doesn't know *why* the date/time changed (the operating system did it); for all the IDE knows, you could have edited the file in an external program or a different copy of the IDE. It's actually *good* that it does this, so you can make sure you're actually working on the current copy of the source. There's no **bug** here.

Comment: Indeed it is actually a bug, but not a major one.It's not expected that the IDE should take this into consideration, since it only happens twice a year in certain regions.

Comment: @Jerry: The US changed the DST rules a few years ago to begin a week earlier and end a week later. It caused quite a few issues, including one in WinXP (until SP2 was released) that MS made a special utility (TZEdit.exe, IIRC) to allow you to manually edit the time zone rules. Without the utility, you'd change the system time and Windows would revert it back. :-)

Comment: I don't see how it can be called a *bug* when it's working exactly as it is designed to work. It's informing you that the time stamp of the file in memory doesn't match the one on disk (and that's factual, because file date/time stamps are based on *local* time, and the local time has changed by an hour). It's not a bug if your software works exactly the way you wanted it to work when you wrote it.

Comment: @Ken, there is the `WM_TIMECHANGE` broadcasted by the system. If the IDE would receive it, it could ignore the upcoming file change event. The question is, if the `WM_TIMECHANGE` message arrives before the file is detected as changed. My guess is that file change detection is faster than the mentioned message and so it's impossible to *"resolve"* this, in my view minor issue easily.

Comment: @TLama: But there's no point in handling that message in the first place. Why add the overhead? It only affects files *actually open at that moment* in the IDE. It's not a bug to ignore a Windows message you don't need to handle.

Comment: In other words, the IDE *could* detect this message and adjust accordingly to avoid this mis-hap, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is ridiculous. OK, let's handle every possible message that affects only files open at 2:00AM on a Sunday morning twice a year, because it's a bug if you don't. Now let's handle every other meaningless, unused message in Windows. We can make the IDE consume 400GB of disk space because of unnecessary code, 24GB of RAM, take 15 seconds to respond to anything, but what the hell - we'll catch those corner niches.

Comment: @KenWhite Exactly, the IDE doesn't handle every possible Windows message because it doesn't find a reason to..

Comment: And it's simply ridiculous to call it a *bug* because it doesn't handle a message it has no reason to handle. :) If you feel this "bug" affects you, there's a simple workaround - close your IDE between 1:59AM and 2:01AM on those two days.

Comment: WM_TIMECHANGE only says that the time has changed, not why it has changed, or by how much. It wouldn't be much use as the IDE couldn't determine if the time change was only due to DST. A better fix would be to use UTC internally for all file time stamps. However I agree with Ken that this is too much of an edge case to bloat the IDE code with.

Comment: @Gerry: Well, it could. It could query the OS for the time zone, then retrieve information about whether or not DST is used (oops, wait - Arizona has areas that do and areas that don't, so it has to be a quite specific check). If DST is supported, it could then query the starting and ending dates of DST, check to see if the system time falls within the acceptable time frames, and then iterate through all of the cached files to update the date/time stamp info. Wow! That's a lot of code for absolutely *no useful purpose*. (Oh, wait. I also forgot disk IO; we'd have to check disk date/time too.)

Comment: The IDE shouldn't be having to handle DST. All it should do is to keep what `GetFileTime` returns for reference - no local conversion.

Comment: @Ken - precisely my point - as we don't know WHY the time has changed or by how much, we can't really do anything about it. When NZDST came on here a month ago, I had this (non) issue, and immediately realised the cause. The "unnecessary recompile" took a few seconds of my time.

Comment: @Gerry: Agreed. I just hate to see things labeled as a "bug" when the actual issue is "we decided not to add tons of code to support something totally silly and immaterial to anything we do, that affects two specific *minutes* in a full year in a very miniscule set of circumstances that probably won't happen, and has basically no impact if it does occur". ;) The workaround is quite simple: In addition to "change the clocks and your smoke detector batteries", add "and shut down the IDE before going to bed" to your DST checklist. :D

Comment: @KenWhite it is a bug, and there is a simple solution.  The bug is specifically using the local clock as the metric - this is an error and there is no reason for it except perhaps for ancient systems that are still using FAT filesystems.  The UTC timestamp of the file would not have changed and the correct implementation of a file-time check should be using UTC time.  It does not require an obscure hack for exceptions at 2AM on two arbitrary days during the year.